# Find the similar words or phrases from two texts

Tags: php, logic

I know how to compare two texts and get all the single words that appear in both. But how can I match expressions/phrases?

For example:
1. "This is the computer maker Apple"
2. "Apple is a California based great computer maker"

Now :)

1. Apple is clearly present in both.
2. computer and maker are present in both. I could check at this point if they are a group of words(one follows the other one).

But for the speed of processing, isn't there a way to match "computer maker" and not each one and then check if present as a group.

Keep in mind that the example given is trivial and just for the purpose of exemplifying, in practice more complicated sentences/texts may be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse both strings and split on whitespace to get token arrays A1 and A2. Then, simply check every contiguous subsequence in A1 for a matching one in A2. This looks like O(n^4) to me, which is better than getting all the single matches and looking for combinations... which is not polynomial.

```
  1. the cat is on the roof
  2. a man is on the stage

  A1 = [the, cat, is, on, the, roof]
  A2 = [a, man, is, on, the, stage]

  [the]: no match
  [cat]: no match
  [is]: match
  [is, on]: match
  [is, on, the]: match
  [is, on, the, roof]: no match
  [on]: match
  [on, the]: match
  [on, the, roof]: no match
  [the]: match
  [the, roof]: no match
  [roof]: no match
  -end-
```

Recursion seems like an elegant way to implement something like this. If you need something more efficient, I'm sure that there is a smarter way to do it than this.

Comment: Hopefully google doesn't use a O(n^4) algorythm to check for content modification in websites.

Comment: True, but a few observations... it's easy to understand, much better than the OP's suggestion, and its average case performance is probably much better than O(n^4), probably closer to O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: It sounds like you might be looking for a solution to [the longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), or more generally [the longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). If that's the case, then you basically want a variation on the "diff" utility, and the details of the implementation of course depend very much on the details of your requirements.

Comment: If he wants all the common strings, this doesn't seem like the right way to go... maybe I'm missing something. Maybe the canonical solution to LCS visits all candidates, so they can be enumerated?

Comment: -1 for answering a question with a question. If this is what you are looking to find out, you should leave it as a comment.

Comment: @barfoon: a semantic quibble, IMO. But I'm no SO expert, so if that's the way we roll here, then fine.

Comment: @Peter - I agree with you, and wasn't trying to be too pedantic, just a good citizen. Thanks for not responding rudely :)

Comment: @barfoon: Since the original poster hasn't made any additional comments, I'll rewrite my counter-question as a conditional answer.